# How do you solve Second Order Differential Equations equal to a fraction like 1/x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem. it is

$y'' + 4y' + 3y = (1/x)$

as you can see, yp will be aqual to

yp = $a1*1/x + a2*1/x^2 + a3*1/x^3...$

How do you solve these kind of equations where yp has no end.

Comment: In this case you can't use the method of undetermined coefficients because the derivatives do not terminate. Instead, I would recommend you use the method of [variation of parameters](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx)

Comment: I see thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite $y''+4y'+3y=\frac{1}{x}$ as $y''+y'+3y'+3y=\frac{1}{x}$. Notice that $y''+y'=(y'+y)'$, and $3y'+3y=3(y'+y)$. Hence $y''+y'+3y'+3y=(y'+y)'+3(y'+y)=\frac{1}{x}$. Let $z=y'+y$. Thus $z'+3z=\frac{1}{x}$. This can be solved using the integration factor. In particular, $\exp(3x)z'+3\exp(3x)z=\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}=[\exp(3x)z]'$. The antiderivatives of $\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}$ are non-elementary. Hence $$z=y'+y=\exp(-3x)\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+A\exp(-3x),\,x\lt0$$ $$z=y'+y=\exp(-3x)\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+B\exp(-3x),\,x\gt0.$$ These can be solved again using the integrating factor. Namely, $$\exp(x)y'+\exp(x)y=[\exp(x)y]'=\exp(-2x)\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+A\exp(-2x),\,x\lt0$$ $$\exp(x)y'+\exp(x)y=[\exp(x)y]'=\exp(-2x)\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+B\exp(-2x),\,x\gt0.$$ This implies $$\exp(x)y=-\frac{\exp(-2x)}{2}\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\int\frac{\exp(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{A}{2}\exp(-2x)+C,\,x\lt0$$ $$\exp(x)y=-\frac{\exp(-2x)}{2}\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\int\frac{\exp(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{B}{2}\exp(-2x)+D,\,x\gt0$$ which simplifies to $$y=-\frac{\exp(-3x)}{2}\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\exp(-x)}{2}\int\frac{\exp(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{A}{2}\exp(-3x)+C\exp(-x),\,x\lt0$$ $$y=-\frac{\exp(-3x)}{2}\int\frac{\exp(3x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\exp(-x)}{2}\int\frac{\exp(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{B}{2}\exp(-3x)+D\exp(-x),\,x\gt0.$$

Comment: thank you very much. I was trying to find different solutions, but couldn't.